# Calling router.get using a redirect in Express

Tags: javascript, express

Is there a way to specifically call a `router.get(...)` function in Express?

Suppose I have a `router.get('/my-route', function(req, res) { ... });`, is it possible then, in some other area of my code, to call `res.redirect('my-route');` and expect it to be caught by the router?

Thanks

Comment: why dont your make use of the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location API, here you ask for your route and do things in case you are there. consider it an approach.

Comment: Are you attempting to call the function in the server or the client?

Comment: @wmash, in the server

Answer (score 0):

Routes define functions to be executed following an HTTP Request. If you want to executed some route defined as `router.get(...)` you need to call `res.redirect()` with an actual route like:

```
res.redirect('/some/path');
```

That should execute the function defined in:

```
app.use('/some/path', someFunction);
```